# Excel/VBA - Worksheet_Change only firing when field changed manually

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

Hi and thank you for any help in advance. I'm new to VBA and I'm not a programmer by any measure. I was able to get VBA code to work for a field change, but it is not triggering when the field change is not done manually.

My exact use case is I uploaded an excel macrobook in to a third party app within Salesforce and mapped fields. The app is sending the field data to excel, it is changing successfully, but not triggering my Worksheet_Change. Here is the full code (basically it shows rows when a field is changed to "True").

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$K$19" And Target.Value = "True" Then

        Worksheets("Form").Activate

            Sheets("Form").Rows("20").Select
                If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If

            Sheets("Form").Rows("41").Select
                If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If

            Sheets("Form").Rows("81:89").Select
                If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If

    End If

End Sub
```

From what I understand, the way to get this to work is to have the same code running as a Worksheet_Calculate. Can anyone provide some info around this? I'm not familiar with Worksheet_Calculates or really Events in general.

Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps the outside program is using Application.EnableEvents = False, which is stopping the Change event from firing.

Comment: It's possible the app you uploaded your file to doesn't use automation to populate the workbook (microsoft recommends again using Office automation in a server environment), but uses some other library to do this.  If that's the case then no VBA will run and none of your events will fire.  It would be foolish of them to allow users to upload arbitrary VBA to their environment, given the potential security implications.

Comment: Your code will only fire if $K$19 is changed, if you want it to fire when other cells are changed then you will need to use the `Intersect()` method to establish the range that should fire the event.

Comment: $k$19 is the cell I am tracking changes in, I guess I wasn't clear with that. The code works great, but only when I change the cell to True and hit Enter, not when it is fed the answer.

As for the program possibly using Application.EnableEvents = False, I don't know for sure. I do know that even mapping $k$19 to another field, and changing that target field (so the "true" is sent to $k$19, not manually input), it won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cells, say cell **Z100** and **Z101**

1. if **Z100** is *manually refreshed,* then the *Change* event can be triggered
2. if **Z100** contains a *formula,* then the *Calculate* event can be triggered.
3. if **Z100** contains a value that is refreshed via an *external feed,* then in **Z101** enter `=Z100` and the *Calculate* event can then also be triggered.

That is because if **Z100** gets refreshed, then **Z101** will automatically be calculated and the event will be triggered!

Comment: I am assuming the OP edited his question after Gary's explanation, so just to expand on Gary's answer.  In the worksheet where you already have your Sub Worksheet_Change, either simply change the procedure name to Worksheet_Calculate or create a new calculate procedure by selecting the event type of Calculate from the drop down list at the top right of the vba editor code window